# Get JPA Transaction outside Controllers - Play Framework

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm using play 1.2.7 on my work. I'm trying to save an entity on database outside a Controller. I start a separated thread and in this thread in want to save some the entity.

It's possible with play to do this? How can I create a new Transaction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to initialize a JPA context and start a transaction by using [`JPAPlugin.startTx(boolean readonly);`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/api/play/db/jpa/JPAPlugin.html#startTx%28boolean%29). Remember to manually close the transaction afterwards with [`JPAPlugin.closeTx(boolean rollback)`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/api/play/db/jpa/JPAPlugin.html#closeTx%28boolean%29).